# HTML Controls Disabled

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, dynamic

I have created an MVC application in which i have a separate partial view for rendering controls and for some reason those controls are disabled.

Following is the Index action method

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string conn = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conn"].ToString();

        List<CustomControl> ctr = new List<CustomControl>();
        DataTable dt = getData("tbl_RowTrack");
        DataTable odt = getData("DynamicData");

        DataRow ds = odt.AsEnumerable().LastOrDefault();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.AsEnumerable())
            ctr.Add(new CustomControl { type = dr[2].ToString(), name = dr[1].ToString(), value = dr[3].ToString(), origVal = ds == null ? null : ds[dr[1].ToString()].ToString() });

        return View(ctr);
    }
```

Following is the Index view

```
@model IEnumerable<List.Models.CustomControl>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<fieldset>
    <legend>Checklist</legend>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddData", "Dynamic", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div id="container">
            @foreach (var mod in Model)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_CustomControl.cshtml", mod);
            }
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    }
</fieldset>
```

Following is the _CustomControl Partial view

```
@model List.Models.CustomControl

@if (Model.type.ToString().Equals("string"))
{
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="margin-bottom:5px; float:left">
        <b>@Model.value</b>
        @Html.TextBox("txt " + Model.name, Model.origVal, new { @class="form-control" })
    </div>
}

@if (Model.type.ToString().Equals("dateTime"))
{
    <div style="margin-bottom:10px; float:left" class="col-xs-4">
        <b>@Model.value</b>
        @Html.TextBox("dt " + Model.name, Model.origVal, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
}

@if (Model.type.ToString().Equals("radio"))
{
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div style="margin-bottom:5px; float:left">
            <b>@Model.value</b>
            <br />
            <div style="margin-top:3px">
                @if (Model.origVal != null && Model.origVal.Trim().Equals("yes"))
                {
                    @Html.RadioButton("rd " + Model.name, "yes", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.RadioButton("rd " + Model.name, "yes");
                }
                &nbsp;Yes
                @if (Model.origVal != null && Model.origVal.Trim().Equals("no"))
                {
                    @Html.RadioButton("rd " + Model.name, "no", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.RadioButton("rd " + Model.name, "no");
                }
                &nbsp;No
                @if (Model.origVal != null && Model.origVal.Trim().Equals("na"))
                {
                    @Html.RadioButton("rd " + Model.name, "na", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.RadioButton("rd " + Model.name, "na");
                }
                &nbsp;N/A
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Nothing in your code is setting the `disabled="disabled"` attribute in any of your form controls!

Comment: but i am not able to select any of the controls